# What are the md partitions under a mdadm array?

Tags: mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I'm setting up two RAID 1 arrays using `mdadm`, it seems to be working fine but when I do a check in `lsblk` I see the following:

```
sda                      8:0    0   5,5T  0 disk  
└─md127                  9:127  0   5,5T  0 raid1 
  ├─data-crypt-1       253:5    0   5,5T  0 crypt 
  │ └─myVg-data        253:6    0   5,5T  0 lvm   
  ├─md127p1            259:5    0 182,4G  0 md    
  └─md127p2            259:6    0   1,2T  0 md    
sdb                      8:16   0   5,5T  0 disk  
└─md127                  9:127  0   5,5T  0 raid1 
  ├─data-crypt-1       253:5    0   5,5T  0 crypt 
  │ └─myVg-data        253:6    0   5,5T  0 lvm   
  ├─md127p1            259:5    0 182,4G  0 md    
  └─md127p2            259:6    0   1,2T  0 md    
sdc                      8:32   0   5,5T  0 disk  
└─md126                  9:126  0   5,5T  0 raid1 
sdd                      8:48   0   5,5T  0 disk  
└─md126                  9:126  0   5,5T  0 raid1
```

What are these partitions (?) `md127p1` and `md127p2` in my array? Should I remove them and, if so, how?

It doesn't seem to interfere with the array, it seems to be resyncing as expected. But I worry that, for example, if someone were to mount say `md127p1` and write something to it, it would corrupt the data in `data-crypt-1` (which is spanning the full drive).

EDIT:

The problem (if it is a problem) persist after reboot and reassembly.

```bsh
sudo wipefs --no-act /dev/md127
# DEVICE OFFSET TYPE        UUID                                 LABEL
# md127  0x0    crypto_LUKS ba3eab9b-db06-4053-9eb8-4e674931148c
```

`dmesg` do report slightly different behavior between `md126` and `md127`. Not sure how to inspect the "background reconstruction".

```bsh
dmesg | grep "md12[67]"
# [    3.072445] md/raid1:md127: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
# [    3.072445] md/raid1:md127: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
# [    3.107577] md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 6001039835136
# [    3.112944]  md127: AHDI p1 p2 p3
# [    4.072578] md/raid1:md126: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
# [    4.105528] md126: detected capacity change from 0 to 6001039835136
# [  175.221344]  md127: AHDI p1 p2 p3
# [  252.627169]  md127: AHDI p1 p2 p3
# [  337.950292]  md127: AHDI p1 p2 p3
```

and `udevadm` reports as follows:

```
udevadm info /dev/md127p1
# P: /devices/virtual/block/md127/md127p1
# N: md127p1
# L: 100
# S: disk/by-id/md-name-XYZ:data-array-1-part1
# S: disk/by-id/md-uuid-94gd622:d96sf22:9fb73768:dae5367e-part1
# S: md/XYZ:data-array-1p1
# E: DEVLINKS=/dev/md/XYZ:data-array-1p1 /dev/disk/by-id/md-name-XYZ:data-array-1-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-94gd622:d96sf22:9fb73768:dae5367e-part1
# E: DEVNAME=/dev/md127p1
# E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/md127/md127p1
# E: DEVTYPE=partition
# E: MAJOR=259
# E: MD_DEVICES=2
# E: MD_DEVICE_ev_sda_DEV=/dev/sda
# E: MD_DEVICE_ev_sda_ROLE=0
# E: MD_DEVICE_ev_sdb_DEV=/dev/sdb
# E: MD_DEVICE_ev_sdb_ROLE=1
# E: MD_DEVNAME=XYZ:data-array-1
# E: MD_LEVEL=raid1
# E: MD_METADATA=1.2
# E: MD_NAME=XYZ:data-array-1
# E: MD_UUID=94gd622:d96sf22:9fb73768:dae5367e
# E: MINOR=5
# E: PARTN=1
# E: SUBSYSTEM=block
# E: SYSTEMD_WANTS=mdmonitor.service
# E: TAGS=:systemd:
# E: USEC_INITIALIZED=337999178
```

```
udevadm info /dev/md127p2
# P: /devices/virtual/block/md127/md127p2
# N: md127p2
# L: 100
# S: disk/by-id/md-name-XYZ:data-array-1-part2
# S: disk/by-id/md-uuid-94gd622:d96sf22:9fb73768:dae5367e-part2
# S: md/XYZ:data-array-1p2
# E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/md-name-XYZ:data-array-1-part2 /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-94gd622:d96sf22:9fb73768:dae5367e-part2 /dev/md/XYZ:data-array-1p2
# E: DEVNAME=/dev/md127p2
# E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/md127/md127p2
# E: DEVTYPE=partition
# E: MAJOR=259
# E: MD_DEVICES=2
# E: MD_DEVICE_ev_sda_DEV=/dev/sda
# E: MD_DEVICE_ev_sda_ROLE=0
# E: MD_DEVICE_ev_sdb_DEV=/dev/sdb
# E: MD_DEVICE_ev_sdb_ROLE=1
# E: MD_DEVNAME=XYZ:data-array-1
# E: MD_LEVEL=raid1
# E: MD_METADATA=1.2
# E: MD_NAME=XYZ:data-array-1
# E: MD_UUID=94gd622:d96sf22:9fb73768:dae5367e
# E: MINOR=6
# E: PARTN=2
# E: SUBSYSTEM=block
# E: SYSTEMD_WANTS=mdmonitor.service
# E: TAGS=:systemd:
# E: USEC_INITIALIZED=337999612
```

`hexdump` shows:

```
sudo hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/md127
# *
# *
# 000001c0  7c e8 03 4d 62 32 d5 66  37 75 6b e9 12 6d 16 cc  ||..Mb2.f7uk..m..|
# 000001d0  96 9e 6f 3d 32 e0 e7 fe  7f f4 9c a1 59 03 19 47  |..o=2.......Y..G|
# 000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
# *
```

I also noted that I don't see the "ghost" partitions on some machines, in particular non of my DietPi Machines show them. They do show on my Ubuntu machine. Additionally, I noted that both arrays (md126 and md127) were created on one of the DietPi machines.

Comment: does it persist after reassemble/reboot? output of `wipefs --no-act /dev/md127`? md devices can be partitioned but `cryptsetup luksFormat` should remove partition tables (both start end of disk) by itself. Unless perhaps your crypt device was set up some other way?

Comment: yes I see the same after reboot/reassemble, `wipefs`, doesn't show any additional partitions. I used `cryptsetup luksFormat` to create the LUKS partition.

Comment: `head /sys/block/md127/md127p*/{start,size}`? `dmesg` of md assembly process? At this point I'm wondering if there is a deliberately created partition table, or some random data getting misinterpreted somehow. Those partitions shouldn't be there and writing to them would corrupt data, whereas re-writing a partition table would corrupt your LUKS header. Not good...

Comment: also `udevadm info /dev/md127p1` and `udevadm info /dev/md127p2`

Comment: added the output from `head /sys/block/md127/md127p*/{start,size}` and `udevadm`, not sure exactly what info I should search for in `dmesg`, for now I did `dmesg | grep "md12[67]"`

Comment: so it thinks it's some AHDI atari partition table... kernels shouldn't even support these anymore. Does `hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/md127` have any of GEM, BGM, LNX, SWP, RAW?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this seems to be a case of a random bogus partition table mis-detection.

Here's an example of an Atari / AHDI partition table (created with parted):

```
# hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/loop0 
000001c0  00 00 00 03 20 00 01 4c  4e 58 00 00 08 00 00 00  |.... ..LNX......|
000001d0  08 00 01 4c 4e 58 00 00  18 00 00 00 60 00 00 50  |...LNX......`..P|
000001e0  41 52 54 45 44 41 54 41  52 49 00 50 41 52 54 45  |ARTEDATARI.PARTE|
000001f0  44 41 54 41 52 49 00 00  00 01 00 00 00 01 fa 70  |DATARI.........p|
```

So the interesting bit is one of GEM, BGM, LNX, SWP, RAW at offset 0x1c0/0x1d0 lines, as can be seen in block/partitions/atari.c#L27-L32:

```
static inline int OK_id(char *s)
{
    return  memcmp (s, "GEM", 3) == 0 || memcmp (s, "BGM", 3) == 0 ||
        memcmp (s, "LNX", 3) == 0 || memcmp (s, "SWP", 3) == 0 ||
        memcmp (s, "RAW", 3) == 0 ;
}
```

Here's an example of a LUKS2 header:

```
# hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/loop1
00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |LUKS..........@.|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a4 43 6c 13 63 6b 33 da  |.........Cl.ck3.|
00000070  c8 f5 1d 7d 82 b3 9e dc  15 b2 ff 55 d2 4c 3e 8c  |...}.......U.L>.|
00000080  62 08 ec 0f 56 b2 bc 89  86 f0 e8 c0 e6 a2 d8 12  |b...V...........|
00000090  56 93 68 2f 83 82 e6 90  18 57 7b 23 34 d7 96 92  |V.h/.....W{#4...|
000000a0  ab ad 67 a5 d9 7d dd 6c  32 36 37 36 35 63 39 32  |..g..}.l26765c92|
000000b0  2d 34 34 37 34 2d 34 36  37 64 2d 62 39 62 62 2d  |-4474-467d-b9bb-|
000000c0  64 36 30 36 63 61 64 31  32 61 62 64 00 00 00 00  |d606cad12abd....|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001c0  55 85 e9 50 c2 46 1e 16  27 a7 ce a5 9d e9 46 17  |U..P.F..'.....F.|
000001d0  fb 30 9a ae 53 74 39 8a  c5 2c d2 21 4b 86 ad 20  |.0..St9..,.!K.. |
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000200
```

So there just happens to be random data just at the same 0x1c0 / 0x1d0 lines.

My guess is that you randomly rolled one of GEM, BGM, LNX, SWP, RAW in there, so it looks like a partition table to the kernel, and hence you got your freak partitions detected.

The good news is that for the LUKS2 header, this offset seems to represent the header checksum. It changes completely every time you change anything in the LUKS2 header, so... you could, for example, just add another passphrase. (and remove it if you don't actually need it).

```
# cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/loop1
Enter any existing passphrase: 
Enter new passphrase for key slot: 
Verify passphrase:
```

Same LUKS2 header after running `cryptsetup luksAddKey`:

```
# hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/loop1
00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |LUKS..........@.|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a4 43 6c 13 63 6b 33 da  |.........Cl.ck3.|
00000070  c8 f5 1d 7d 82 b3 9e dc  15 b2 ff 55 d2 4c 3e 8c  |...}.......U.L>.|
00000080  62 08 ec 0f 56 b2 bc 89  86 f0 e8 c0 e6 a2 d8 12  |b...V...........|
00000090  56 93 68 2f 83 82 e6 90  18 57 7b 23 34 d7 96 92  |V.h/.....W{#4...|
000000a0  ab ad 67 a5 d9 7d dd 6c  32 36 37 36 35 63 39 32  |..g..}.l26765c92|
000000b0  2d 34 34 37 34 2d 34 36  37 64 2d 62 39 62 62 2d  |-4474-467d-b9bb-|
000000c0  64 36 30 36 63 61 64 31  32 61 62 64 00 00 00 00  |d606cad12abd....|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001c0  2a 11 50 fd 0b 8a 05 b6  67 1a e5 2f 2b a7 de d5  |*.P.....g../+...|
000001d0  2c b3 17 7c a5 21 b5 a1  5a f3 86 5c 96 9e 16 c0  |,..|.!..Z..\....|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000200
```

As you can see the data in 0x1c0/0x1d0 rowns changed completely from before, so with any luck, your bogus partition table will also be gone (after re-reading partition tables). At the same time it's something worth looking out for as any future change to the header could bring it back...

---

I assume you're using LUKS2 because the old LUKS1 header does not store random data at this offset, and `luksFormat` also zeroes it out like this:

```
000001c0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

So this problem shouldn't even be occuring with the old LUKS1 header format.

Comment: I couldn't see GEM, BGM, LNX, SWP or RAW in the output from `hexdump`. I did try to run the array on a couple of different machines though, and it seems I don't see these "ghost" partitions on all machines. I see them in Ubuntu my installation but not in my DietPi installations. The arrays (both md126 and 127) were created on one of the DietPi machines.

Comment: @ChristianEriksson check /proc/config.gz for CONFIG_ATARI_PARTITION, if "is not set" then that kernel doesn't support atari partitions and won't see them (sane choice anyway, but if you are using distro provided kernel, you can't control it). I'm not too familiar with this partition type; it might be it can live at other offsets too, in which case, my answer might not apply. :-/

Comment: You can re-generate the entire LUKS header with `cryptsetup convert` (to LUKS1 and back to LUKS2) which would overwrite (almost) all random parts of it (new checksum, new key material, new salts, etc.) so you might get rid of it that way (if its in another portion of the LUKS header). If it's at the end of the device, things would be more difficult (to LUKS, that's the data area)

Comment: Old partition types are really troublesome since they don't have good magic bytes to reliably identify by, there's also a comment to that in the source code, `/*
   * if there's no valid primary partition, assume that no Atari
   * format partition table (there's no reliable magic or the like
          * :-()
   */`

Comment: I did find `CONFIG_ATARI_PARTITION=y` for the Ubuntu install. Wasn't able to find the kernel config for DietPi (in /proc nor /boot). But seeing that it's supposed to be a very minimal Debian based distro perhaps it's safe to assume it's not included. I'll see if I can regenerate the entire header with `cryptsetup convert`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! After backing up the header and converting the keys from argon2i to pbkdf2 to allow for LUKS 2 -> LUKS 1 convertion, `cryptsetup convert` back and forth between LUKS 2 and 1 did remove my ghost partitions. I believe you were absolutely on the money. Thanks a bunch for all your input and help, much appreciated!