# Creating a new raid1 mdadm luks device creates two unwanted partitions

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I am trying to create a raid1 (with `mdadm`) device with `luks`. However, it creates two partitions instead of one as you can see below:

```
sde              8:64   0   3,6T  0 disk  
`-sde1           8:65   0   3,6T  0 part  
  `-md0          9:0    0   3,6T  0 raid1 
    |-storage2 253:2    0   3,6T  0 crypt 
    |-md0p1    259:0    0 750,7G  0 part  
    `-md0p2    259:1    0   1,4T  0 part  
sdf              8:80   0   3,6T  0 disk  
`-sdf1           8:81   0   3,6T  0 part  
  `-md0          9:0    0   3,6T  0 raid1 
    |-storage2 253:2    0   3,6T  0 crypt 
    |-md0p1    259:0    0 750,7G  0 part  
    `-md0p2    259:1    0   1,4T  0 part
```

This is the procedure I used:

```
cfdisk /dev/sde
cfdisk /dev/sdf
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/md0
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md0 storage2
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/storage2
mkdir -p /media/storage2
mount /dev/mapper/storage2 /media/storage2
```

Why using `lsblk` I see two partitions for both `sde` and `sdf`? How can I avoid it?

EDIT: When creating the array with `mdadm`, I get the following, maybe this could be the cause of the problem, but how do I get rid of it?

```
$ mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
mdadm: /dev/sde1 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Mon Jan 23 20:01:19 2023
mdadm: Note: this array has metadata at the start and
    may not be suitable as a boot device.  If you plan to
    store '/boot' on this device please ensure that
    your boot-loader understands md/v1.x metadata, or use
    --metadata=0.90
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Mon Jan 23 20:01:19 2023
mdadm: size set to 3906885440K
mdadm: automatically enabling write-intent bitmap on large array
Continue creating array?
```

Comment: Should be something old left over... `fdisk -l`, `wipefs` (careful with that one), ...? if mdadm is using 1.2 metadata, you can zero first 4096 bytes, or just remove partition type metadata with wipefs (careful to not wipe mdadm metadata or luks headers)

Comment: The hard drives are brand new, I don't mind reformatting them. However, I would do it with the same procedure I wrote in my question and I would obtain the same result

Comment: If you don't mind re-doing it, then just `wipefs -a` (and/or zero 1M start&end) of every block device before formatting it (for sde, sdf, sde1, sdf1, md0, ...). with LUKS in particular there is a case that [random data in the luks header is sometimes mis-interpreted as a partition table](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561907/30851) (some exotic partition table formats don't have proper headers) but that does not seem to be your problem, especially if its repeatable

Comment: No success :(. As I create a new partition on sde and sdf they are automatically added to md0 and the two partitions on each device are created. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `mdadm --stop`, `mdadm --zero-superblock` to get rid of previously created RAID

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Do everything as before but then:

```
fdisk /dev/md0
d
w
q
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/md0
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/storage2
mkdir -p /media/storage2
mount /dev/mapper/storage2 /media/storage2
```